# Angular Filter for Object

Tags: angularjs, object, filter

I am trying to use filter in order to match a newly selected name from a select element using ng-options with the names ID.

The object I'm working with looks like:

```
 $scope.fish = {1:'Ben', 2: 'Rich', 3:'John'}
```

Right now the select is set to "John" by default. When the user changes the select option to lets say "Rich", I want the filter function give me back 2 (which is Rich's corresponding ID).

Assume that:

```
$scope.selectedFish
```

only stores the name and not the ID for a fish.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/purple_lightsaber/3gz2dedh/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
<div data-ng-app="market">
  <div data-ng-controller="SomeController">
    <select ng-model="selectedFish" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in fish" ng-change="getIdByName()"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.fish = {
    1: 'Ben',
    2: 'Rich',
    3: 'John'
  }
  $scope.getIdByName = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.fish, function(value, key) {
      if (key == $scope.selectedFish) {
        console.log("selected key is " + $scope.selectedFish + "selected value is " + value);
      }
    });
  }

}]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/z504gf8t/)**

Comment: much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following solution

```
$scope.fish = {1:'Ben', 2: 'Rich', 3:'John'};
$scope.selected = 'Rich';

var getValue = function(){
    var result = "";
    angular.forEach($scope.fish, function(value, key) {
        if (value == $scope.selected) {
           result = key;
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Hope this is help.

Comment: thanks , you and Sajeetharan basically had the same solutions